# Cells in table style

Tags: html, css, styles

I have a table.  The first row of it contains one cell,after I added a second row, the first cell of my second row takes the width of the above cell(first row). Is there any relationship between the cells in different rows at the same table?

Comment: please show the HTML you have, and maybe provide a screenshot what your problem is

Comment: i have table contain two row the first contain one cell the second contain five cells the first of five take the same width of cell in the first row,can you give me code

Comment: You are asking us, to write a code for you.. Without giving us your current code.. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: @CTravel, please do not link to w3schools. See http://www.w3fools.com for reason. Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Answer (score 2):

All cells in each columns of the table will always have the same width much like an Excel spreadsheet. If you want different sizes, use colspan, that works similar to merging cells in Excel

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=5>Row 1 col 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>R2 C1</td><td>R2 C2</td><td>R2 C3</td><td>R2 C4</td><td>R2 C5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i have table contain two row the first contain one cell the second contain five cells the first of five take the same width of cell in the first row,can you give me code